# .js help with the Date object and if/else

Tags: javascript

ok so im trying to create something where certain elements change based on time of day. that time of day is gotten via system clock.

heres my code:

```
var currTime = new Date();


var currHrs = currTime.getHours();
var currMins = currTime.getMinutes();
var currSecs = currTime.getSeconds();



if (currMins < 10){
  currMins = "0" + currMins;
}


var suffix = "AM";
  if (currHrs >= 12) {
  suffix = "PM";
  currHrs = currHrs - 12;
  }
  if (currHrs == 0) {
  currHrs = 12;
  }



//display thr and minutes .
var myTime = currHrs + ":" + currMins;



if(myTime< 12){
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = myTime;    
} else {
    //code here

}
```

problem im having is that the time isnt being written at all in the html "clock" div.
i know it works because if i take out the 'if' and just do the document.write etc, its prints to screen.

im assuming that the problem is the myTime > 12 part. if i do '>' or '<' , it still doesnt work.

what i want is that say for example, if its before 12pm something happens, etc. i just dont know how to target for example, morning time from noon, night etc.

any ideas, etc ill gladly appreciate.

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your problem is your if condition, or perhaps what comes before it.

```
//display thr and minutes .
var myTime = currHrs + ":" + currMins;
```

You have created `myTime` as a string e.g. `"12:30"`.  Obviously this is not suitable for comparison with a number.

It won't work with `currHrs` either because, with your logic, that is never a number less than 12.

I suggest you map out in pseudo code what it is you are trying to accomplish, as it all seems a bit muddled up there.

Comment: lol thanks for your reply. im still learning, i assumed that the numbers gotten we still numbers not a string output. but what i want in "pseudo code " lol is, if(my current time < 12pm or am){ do something } .

Comment: ok nvm, i figured it out. you gave me a DEEP clue lol. i used parseInt to convert my string to ints and then did the if/else. works. thank you and thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. I simply moved a few things around for you.

**Edited**: Made a few mistakes in my haste. And apologies for syntax error. Fixed now.

```
var currTime = new Date();

var currHrs = currTime.getHours();
var currMins = currTime.getMinutes();
var currSecs = currTime.getSeconds();

if (currMins < 10) {
  currMins = "0" + currMins;
}

var suffix = "AM";
if (currHrs >= 12) {
  suffix = "PM";
  currHrs = currHrs - 12;
} else if (currHrs == 0) {
  currHrs = 12;
}

var myTime = (currHrs == 0 ? 12 : currHrs) + ":" + currMins + " " + suffix;

if (myTime.match(/(AM)/)) {
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = myTime;    
} else {
  // code here
}
```

Comment: hello there, thanks for the response. i see what your trying to do but i get syntax error when i copy/pasted your code. i tried to re-arrange but same thing in DW and aptana.

Comment: ok i found it. " (myTime.match(/(am)/))" ...but thanks let me test to see ifit works

Comment: Sorry, was missing a parentheses. It should work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

After this line myTime is a string

```
var myTime = currHrs + ":" + currMins;
```

You're doing a string comparison to an int below.

```
if(myTime< 12){
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = myTime;    
} else {
    //code here

}
```

Did you mean to do this ?

```
if(currHrs < 12){
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = myTime;    
} else {
    //code here

}
```