# javascript Date or next date based on time of day and if/else

Tags: javascript

I want to show the my current shipping time on my website.  Each day I have a 2:00 pm cut of and would like the date to change to the following week day. Right now I have to manually change it every day

```
Currently Shipping:
Tuesday, April, 24th
Cut-off Time:
2:00 pm PST
```

I have done enough research to believe this is possible but I do not know enough about manipulating the script myself to take the pieces and put it all together.

The two o'clock doesn't usually change so I hope I can use a script to automatically change (just the Day, Month and Date) at the specified time

Please advise Thanks!

What I have tried to put together so far

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getDay();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var date = currentTime.getDate();
var thehour = datetoday.getHours();
if(thehour < 14) { document.write(day + "," + month + "," + date) }
else if (thehour > 14) ...
```

Comment: So the code you've already got looks like ...

Comment: Do it on the server, you can't trust the client's clock for a business purpose.

Comment: What I have tried to put together so far:'code' var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getDay()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var date = currentTime.getDate()
var thehour = datetoday.getHours()

if(thehour < 14){
document.write(day + "," + month + "," + date)
}else if (thehour > 14);{

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7508997 This looks like it would work but I am confused as to exactly what to change to get day month date still looking...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must do this on the server since the client machine doesn't know the right time zone offset (it might be -8 hours or -7 hours depending on whether it's daylight saving time or not) and the client clock may not be accurately set (or might be deliberately incorrectly set).

So if you are going to send the offset to the client, you might as well just send the time. And when you send the zone, don't just send PST since that is ambiguous to many, send the actual offset (UTC -8 or -7 as appropriate). Or send the cutoff time in UTC and let the user work it out.

As an example, to convert the local time to some other time zone, you can do:

```
var pstOffset = 480; // Standard time offset
var pdtOffset = 420  // Daylight saving offset
var now = new Date();

// Adjust to PST
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + now.getTimezoneOffset() - pstOffset);

alert(now); // Time in PST
```

But note that the date object is still in the local time zone because you can't change the actual offset, only adjust the time to allow for it.

To send the cut-off time and convert it to a local time, the easiest way is to send a UTC timestamp and convert it on the local box, so:

```
var ts  = '2012-04-24T08:00:00Z'; // UTC cut-off for standard time on 24/4
var tsd = '2012-04-24T07:00:00Z'; // UTC cut-off for daylight saving time on 24/4

function utcToLocal(s) {
  var bits = s.split(/[-T:Z]/g); // Split string into useful bits
  var d = new Date();

  // Set local date object to UTC supplied time
  d.setUTCFullYear(bits[0], bits[1] - 1, bits[2]);
  d.setUTCHours(+bits[3], +bits[4], +bits[5]);
  return d;
}

alert( 'Your clock says it\'s now ' + (new Date()) +
       '\nThe cut-off for shipping is ' + utcToLocal(ts));
```

And send the appropriate UTC timestamp based on the server time (e.g. if they've missed the shipping time for 24 April, send them the one for 25 April).

#### Edit

Here's a full solution, but remember I've said don't do this on the client:

```
/* Get the cut-off of 2pm PST or PDT on current or
 * next working day. If d is true (e.g. 1) use PDT, 
 * otherwise use PST   
**/
function setCutoffTime(d) {
  var pstOffset = 480; // PST offset in minutes
  var psdOffset = 420; // PDT offset in minutes
  var now = new Date();
  var addDays = 0;
  var cutoff;
  var days = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun'.split(' ');
  var months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'.split(' ');

  // Utility to add a leading zero      
  function addZ(n) {
    return (n<10?'0':'') + n;
  }

  // Convert to PST time
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 
                 now.getTimezoneOffset() - (d? psdOffset : pstOffset));

  // If after 2pm, push to tomorrow
  if (now.getHours() > 14) now.setHours(now.getHours() + 12);

  // If on a weekend, push to Monday
  if (now.getDay() == 6) addDays = 2;
  if (now.getDay() == 0) addDays = 1;

  now.setDate(now.getDate() + addDays);

  // Now on working day pre 2pm, so set time to 14:00
  now.setHours(14, 0, 0);

  // And convert back to local time
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset() + 
                 (d? psdOffset : pstOffset));

  // Return a formatted string - should  be a separate function
  return 'Shipping cut-off: ' + 
          addZ(now.getHours()) + ':' +
          addZ(now.getMinutes()) + ' on ' +
          days[now.getDay()] + ', ' +
          now.getDate() + ' ' +
          months[now.getMonth()] +
          ', ' + now.getFullYear();
}

alert(setCutoffTime()); // Cut-off for PST
alert(setCutoffTime(true)); // Cut-off for PDT
```

Comment: That makes sense, but Right now I just have the time as text it doesn't need to change so I would do this to make sure the other coding I figure out will work accurately? I just want the date to change each afternoon

Comment: So just do it on the server. Or just say "Shipping cut-off is 2pm PST (UTC -8 hrs) Monday to Friday" or similar, then you don't need to change it each day.

Comment: I will give it a go, I appreciate your time to respond to my question

Comment: ok so is the code I am trying to use for my date on track or way off because I am still not sure what to put after the "else" to get the next date to show

Comment: Yes! Now I just have to figure out how to get it on my page. I am excited. I have been trying to figure this out on and off for over a month!